# Let middleware read response from http handler

Tags: go, negroni

I'm building a web service in Go. I use Negroni, unrolled/Render and Gorilla Mux.

I'm trying to write some simple middleware myself for caching http responses and being completly new to Golang a few questions came up...

Is there a way in which I can read what a handler's render.JSON(...) was when my midlleware is executed from the return of the handler.

Demo code below...

```
func MyMiddleWareHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request,next http.HandlerFunc) {
    // First call the next/final handler
    next(w, r)
    //Now read the Render.JSON(...) executed by the handler called by next method above...  
}
```

Comment: See here for some examples on hijacking the ResponseWriter - https://justinas.org/writing-http-middleware-in-go/

Comment: you should look gin framework. http://gin-gonic.github.io/gin ,it has lot of good api to read and render json.